# How to create java http proxy/router to route different types of soap requests between 2 different servers

Tags: java, web-services, soap, proxy, http-proxy

I am trying to create a proxy/router app which will route several different types of SOAP requests to either Server 1 or Server 2 depending on some of the content in the request. Since it has to handle different types of SOAP requests, I have to write at HTTP or TCP layer.

I am evaluating these options:

1. Use a java http proxy like [LittleProxy](https://github.com/adamfisk/LittleProxy), [HTTP-Proxy-Servlet](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet) etc
2. Write a simple web endpoint which accepts request and calls the backend services
3. Use a TCP layer proxy instead of http layer

Is there a better approach than this?

[image: Request flow]

Comment: This is a very good fit for the Content Based Routing Pattern(EIP Patterns). You can find this functionality in Apache Camel and other EIP toolkits.